# Starting child activity from notification

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I have an activity A, the base UI of a music player, containing lists of songs, ecc. It is bound to a Service. This Service is the one that creates a notification for the songs.

Activity B has A as a parent, only has textViews with the song information. When started form A, B also binds to that service as A unbinds, and viceversa again when pressing "back" button (Whoever has Spotify on their phones, A is basically the whole app, B is only the screen showing you the album cover and playback buttons).

B's onCreate and binding to the music Service obviously doesn't kill A, as it can return to it easily, but B does get created every time when called from A, and destroyed if user returns to A.

As I'm listening to music in the background, the notification is of course supposed to take me from wherever I am (whether I'm currently on A, or on any other app on my phone), to B which has the music info and playback controls.

So essentially I want to start B by clicking on the notification, and have A ready to get back to. Instead, what's happening is that B gets created while A (whether in the foreground or not) gets destroyed, killing the service with it as well. B is started but...has nothing.

Which flags are needed for the intent and pendingIntent that I have to pass to the notification's .setContentIntent()? Many are the combinations I've tried, with FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP or FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, and yet such a seemingly simple thing seems to be so hard.

Comment: post your manifest and the code you use to create the Notification